# How to take intersection of 2 or more lists that includes tuples?

Tags: python

I want to compare tuples in two or more lists and print out the intersection of them. I have 25 element (which includes empty) in every tuple and tuple count changes in every list.

So far I have tried taking intersection of two lists, the code that I used can be seen below :

```
res_final = set(tuple(x) for x in res).intersection(set(tuple(x) for x in res1))

output:

set()
```

(res and res1 are my lists)

Comment: Is the MySQL tag necessary?

Comment: and whats the error, unexpected/expected result?

Comment: what is res and res1?

Comment: They are the lists that I try to take intersection of.

Comment: @Triath: it would be easier to answer your question if you gave some example of how `res` and `res1` look like. It does not need to be the entire data, just a couple of elements from each list ... ideally with an element that is actually intersected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this example helps:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)  # random seed for repeatability
a_ = np.random.randint(15,size=(1000,2))  # create random data for tuples
b_ = np.random.randint(15,size=(1000,2))  # create random data for tuples
a, b = set(tuple(d) for d in a_), set(tuple(d) for d in b_)  # set of tuples
intersection = a&b  # intersection
print(intersection)  # result
```

In the code, matrices of random variables are created, then the rows are converted to tuples. Then we get the set of tuples and finally the important part for you, the intersection of the tuples.

Comment: Tried this way too, still output is set().

Comment: then there is no intersection

Answer (score 0):

If your input looks something like this:

```
in_1 = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
in_2 = [(4, 4), (5, 5), (1, 1)]
in_3 = [(6, 6), (7, 7), (1, 1)]
ins = [in_1, in_2, in_3]
```

then I think you can use `itertools.combinations` to find pairwise intersections, and then take a `set` from them in order to remove duplicates.

```
from itertools import combinations

intersected = []
for first, second in combinations(ins, 2):
    elems = set(first).intersection(set(second))
    intersected.extend(elems)

dedup_intersected = set(intersected)
print(dedup_intersected)
# {(1, 1)}
```